# How do I change the Add-in folder location for Visual Studio 2008/2010 so I can install Chirpy

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, chirpy

Addins are currently trying to be added to :
My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Addins and
My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Addins

Due to our network setup, that's off on a backed up network share.

When I try to install [Chirpy](http://chirpy.codeplex.com/) our network policy kicks in and says I cannot copy a DLL to that location.

How do I change the location extensions are installed in?
The Chirpy installer doesn't give you a chance to change the install location so guessing it gets this from VS somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get around this issue.

The Chirpy.vsi file can be renamed to .zip.

This allows me to get the contents out.

From the Tools menu->Options->Enviornment->Add-in/Macros Security

Added a new file path on my C drive, and dropped the 3 Chirpy files in there.

Chirpy then appears in the Add In Manager at Tools-> Add In Manager, tick the checkbox to start it on Startup.

Restarted VS, Chirpy works like a charm.